# change uri without use input output in jena

Tags: sparql, jena

Below is my simple sparql query. I want to change my sparql query uri but i have no idea how can i change this specific thing without using input/output.

input string:

```
PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> 

SELECT ?craigEmail
WHERE
{ ab:craig ab:email ?craigEmail . }
```

output string:

```
PREFIX ab: <http://example.com#> 

SELECT ?craigEmail
WHERE
{ ab:craig ab:email ?craigEmail . }
```

Can you please provide me code to this simple thing in jena...

Comment: Do you just want to replace all URIs prefixed by `http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook` with URIs prefixed by `http://example.com#` in your triplestore using SPARQL query?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I guess yes, so a "simple" SPARQL update query with String hacks would be the way to go.

Comment: @Kalpesh: What you mean is to change the RDF data such that you have another namespace for the URIs.

Comment: @AKSW   Can you please provide me java code?

Comment: You don't need Java code. Ok, you could do this but you could also write a [SPARQL 1.1 Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/) query to modify the data.

Comment: I do not want to change RDF data . i want to only change prefix's URI in query. Simply i want to modify only query.

Comment: @AKSW Can you write update query to modify URI?

Comment: Ok, so you mean that you want to modify the SPARQL query programmatically?  That's a bit trickier if you want to be sound and complete (Jena ARQ is the way to go), but on a first glance you could simply try to use Java String replacement and see whether it's enough

Comment: No, I was wrong - now that you said that you don't want to modify the data.

Comment: @AKSW we have that constrain that we have to do this using jena

Comment: Ehm, and you tried what? Documentation + Javadoc would be a good start. Doing your homework is usually not my preferred goal...

Comment: we tried to find it out but we cant find any clue , and this is a small part of our project so it would be great if you will help us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Jena ARQ API and replace the namespace for the prefix `ab` programmatically by iterating over the triple pattern elements of a SPARQL query:

```java
import org.apache.jena.graph.Node;
import org.apache.jena.graph.NodeFactory;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Triple;
import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.core.TriplePath;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.syntax.ElementPathBlock;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.syntax.ElementTriplesBlock;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.syntax.ElementVisitorBase;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.syntax.ElementWalker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Query query = QueryFactory.create("" +
                "PREFIX ab: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#> " +
                "SELECT ?craigEmail WHERE { ab:craig ab:email ?craigEmail . }");

        // This will walk through all parts of the query// This will walk through all parts of the query

        final String ns = "http://example.com#";

        ElementWalker.walk(query.getQueryPattern(), new ElementVisitorBase() { // ...when it's a block of triples...
            public void visit(ElementPathBlock el){ // ...go through all the triples...
                Iterator<TriplePath> triples = el.patternElts();
                List<Triple> newTriples = new ArrayList<>();
                while (triples.hasNext()) {
                    TriplePath triple = triples.next();
                    if(triple.isTriple()) {
                        Node s = triple.getSubject();
                        if(s.isURI()) {
                            String localName = s.getLocalName();
                            s = NodeFactory.createURI(ns + localName);
                        }
                        Node p = triple.getPredicate();
                        if(p.isURI()) {
                            String localName = p.getLocalName();
                            p = NodeFactory.createURI(ns + localName);
                        }
                        Node o = triple.getSubject();
                        if(o.isURI()) {
                            String localName = o.getLocalName();
                            o = NodeFactory.createURI(ns + localName);
                        }

                        newTriples.add(Triple.create(s, p, o));


                    } else {
                        // TODO handle triple path
                    }
                    triples.remove();
                }
                for(Triple t : newTriples) {
                    el.addTriple(t);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(ElementTriplesBlock el) {
                Iterator<Triple> triples = el.patternElts();
                List<Triple> newTriples = new ArrayList<>();
                while (triples.hasNext()) {
                    Triple triple = triples.next();

                    Node s = triple.getSubject();
                    if(s.isURI()) {
                        String localName = s.getLocalName();
                        s = NodeFactory.createURI(ns + localName);
                    }
                    Node p = triple.getPredicate();
                    if(p.isURI()) {
                        String localName = p.getLocalName();
                        p = NodeFactory.createURI(ns + localName);
                    }
                    Node o = triple.getSubject();
                    if(o.isURI()) {
                        String localName = o.getLocalName();
                        o = NodeFactory.createURI(ns + localName);
                    }

                    newTriples.add(Triple.create(s, p, o));

                    triples.remove();
                }
                for(Triple t : newTriples) {
                    el.addTriple(t);
                }
            }
        });

        query.setPrefix("ab", ns);
        System.out.println(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: PREFIX  ab:   <http://example.com#>
we did it before and it give us following as a output
SELECT  ?craigEmailWHERE
WHERE
  { <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#craig> <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#email> ?craigEmail }

Comment: it changes a base uri but it replace prefix before triplate

Comment: Thanks for send me a code....But please send me your whole  java code because code give me some import problem. can you please provide import  file.

Comment: Oh man...how are you writing Java code?! Any IDE should allow you to add the imports. `Ctrl + Shift + o` in Eclipse for instance...I added it this time, next time it's your turn...

Comment: Soory but it give me same output as previous...

PREFIX  ab:   <http://example.com#>

SELECT  ?craigEmail
WHERE
  { <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#craig> <http://learningsparql.com/ns/addressbook#email> ?craigEmail }

Comment: It causes this type of problrm can you give me solution please....Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jena.atlas.lib.Cache.getIfPresent(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
 at org.apache.jena.enhanced.EnhGraph.getNodeAs(EnhGraph.java:118)
 at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.IteratorFactory.asResource(IteratorFactory.java:71)
 at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.IteratorFactory.asResource(IteratorFactory.java:62)

Comment: Sorry man, but I gave you the correct answer. Obviously, you have some library conflicts, i.e. you have different versions of Jena or of one of its dependencies in your project. Either you use Maven with the `jena-arq` artifact or you have to use the Jar files from the latest Jena distribution - but always use the same version. And use Jena 3.3.0

Comment: And it does **not** give you the same output as previous. You never run my code I guess...I did and it returns the desired output.